# How to reload Live wallpaper on preference change?

Tags: android, live, reload, wallpaper, preference

How can I reload my wallpaper once the preferences are changed? The cube sample does not reload once we change preferences, instead it passes the new preferences. In simple words, How can we have the "Loading live wallpaper.." screen after the prefs are changed? 
Can i add something to onVsibilityChanged? 
Yes we can use the shared values and change the wallpaper, but how to reload the whole thing?

Comment: Tried everything. What I wanted is to decrease the memory usage when we select the live wallpaper settings when the same wallpaper is applied.

Comment: Did you come up with something? I'm wondering also what is the best method to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You could hook something up to the onVisibilityChanged method. Whenever you return from the preference settings, the visible variable will be set to true and the event will fire.

I'm guessing that you'd like to recreate the wallpaper with the new preferences. In that case you could call the your wallpaper's init method when the visibility changes, and the preferences have changed.